# ASP.NET MVC System.NotSupportedException LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have written a query which is as follows:

```
var model = (from r in _db.Restaurants
     join rev in _db.Reviews
     on r.Id equals rev.RestaurantId
     into rest_rev
     from rr in rest_rev.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select new RestaurantViewModel
     {
        Id=r.Id,
        Name=r.Name,
        City=r.City,
        Country=r.Country,
        NumberofReviews=r.Reviews.Count,
        Reviews=rr.Body
     });
```

Before making some changes this query worked fine and then I made some changes (which I don't remember), then it started issuing this error
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l37U4.png)

My Entities are as follows

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RestaurantReview> Reviews { get; set; }
}

public class RestaurantReview
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string ReviewerName { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
}

public class RestaurantViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int NumberofReviews { get; set; }
    public string Reviews { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: You need to convert your LINQ query to List right after the join.

Comment: tried it doesn't work ......

Comment: How did you try it? Post your updated code.

Comment: By the way, you don't need a join in this query. Why is the Reviews property of your ViewModel a string property? Each restaurant can have multiple Reviews. So, Reviews should be a collection.

Comment: ` var model = (from r in _db.Restaurants
                        join rev in _db.Reviews
                        on r.Id equals rev.RestaurantId
                        into rest_rev
                        from rr in rest_rev
                        select new RestaurantViewModel
                        {
                            Id = r.Id,
                            Name=r.Name,
                            City=r.City,
                            Country=r.Country,
                            Reviews=rr.ReviewerName
                            

                        }).ToList();`

Comment: You didn't answer my second question.

Comment: I said you should convert the LINQ query to List right after the join, not at the end. But, again, you don't even need a join.

Comment: @ataravati Thank you .... and Sorry for being late .... I solved it using the same query the problem was that **RestaurantViewModel** some how got treated as an entity in the dbcontext class ..... Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this...

```
List<RestaurantViewModel> listViewModel = new List<RestaurantViewModel>();

var model =  _db.Restaurants.Include("Reviews").ToList().ForEach((item) =>
            {
                RestaurantViewModel viewmodel = new RestaurantViewModel();

               viewmodel.ID = item.ID
               viewmodel.NumberofReviews = item.Reviews.Count;
               ....

                listViewModel.Add(viewmodel);

            });
```